# Перевод из одной системы счисления в любую другую

Tags: c

```
  char digit(short num) 
{
    switch (num)
    {
    case 0: return '0';
    case 1: return '1';
    case 2: return '2';
    case 3: return '3';
    case 4: return '4';
    case 5: return '5';
    case 6: return '6';
    case 7: return '7';
    case 8: return '8';
    case 9: return '9';
    case 10: return 'A';
    case 11: return 'B';
    case 12: return 'C';
    case 13: return 'D';
    case 14: return 'E';
    case 15: return 'F';
    }
}

    #include <limits.h>
    #include <math.h>

    main()
    {
        short c;
        c = (6 * (pow(8, 2)) + (2 * 8) + (5 * (pow(8, 0))));//перевод из 8-чной СС в 10-чную
        //нужно перевести в 33-чную систему счисления

        _getch();
    }
```

Подскажите кто знает.Перевод без строк и массивов

перевести 625 из 8 СС в 33-ю СС (тип short)

Comment: Если вы хотите напечатать `c` в 33-ричной системе счисления, то 1) определите алфавит (какими символами  должны изображаться цифры этой СС; 2) в цикле делите число `c` на 33 (основание СС) и запоминайте остатки от деления (это будут цифры в 33-СС), пока `c != 0`, после чего выводите остатки в обратном порядке

Comment: Что подсказать?

Comment: avp, у меня не получается реализовать код...

Comment: Что именно не получается, в ответе же @freim вам уже все написал?

Answer (score 1):

```
//
// Функция преобразует число в заданную систему счисленияю
// Возвращает true если успешно,
// возвращает false если заданное основание системы счисления слишком велико
// Размер буфера вывода должен быть не менее 65 символов (макс размер
// long long в двоичном виде + завершающий 0).
//

bool Convert(unsigned long long num, char* outBuf, unsigned radix) {
  static const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";  // Цифры
  static const int maxRadix = sizeof(digits) - 1;   // Макс основание == число цифр

  if (radix > maxRadix) return false;  // Цифр не хватает для заданного основания

  char* p = outBuf;

  // Этот цикл помещает цифры в буфер в обратном порядке
  do {
    *(p++) = digits[(unsigned)(num % radix)];
    num /= radix;
  } while (num != 0);

  // Завершить строку нулем и перевернуть цифры в правильный порядок
  *p = '\0';
  _strrev(outBuf);
  return true;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
int main {
  char buf[65];
  Convert(625, buf, 33);
  printf(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: мне не нужно строками и массивами, нужно сделать обычными вычислениями

Comment: @King.cmikhail Это должно было быть написано в вопросе.

Comment: @King.cmikhail Что значит "без строк"? Говорить о системе счисления в отрыве от строк невозможно, потому что система счисления - это представление числа для человека, в виде строки. В компьютере никаких систем счисления нет. Точнее, есть только одна, аппаратно заданная, которую сменить невозможно. Как вы преобразованное-то число собрались хранить? Если не в строку его записывать, то куда?

Comment: ок понятно.....